# django one widget for two m2m fields

Tags: django, django-widget

I have two manytomany fields for my model ModelFrom, that both go to the same Model, call it ModelTo.

```
ModelFrom(models.Model):
    field_one = ManyToManyField(ModelTo)
    checked = ManyToManyField(ModelTo)
```

checked is a subset of field one. I have properly validated this in model clean() and adminform clean() methods, and updated model::save() to call self.full_clean().

Ideally, I would have one widget, much like the django.forms.SelectMultiple, but with a checkbox inside each `<option>`.

what it currently looks like, I have one of these widgets for each field:
[image: current look]:

I want to combine them and have a checkbox or something, here is my unicode representation of what it would look like

{  [ blah: 2 ☐] , [blah: 1 ☑] }

Value in the list -> field one is set. Checked box -> checked is set as it is a subset of field_one.

I have seen jQuery UI MultiSelect Widget but there doesn't seem to be a way to be able to select an option, but not check the box.

Comment: I am not totally clear what you want to achieve, but could a ModelMultipleChoiceField with a CheckboxSelectMultiple do the job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't directly answer my own question, but like most questions, if the answer is not possible then there may be an underlying problem.

Instead of having two many2many fields, I should just have one, setting the through property, for an intermediate field.
Like so:

```
class IntermediateField(models.Model):
     checked = BooleanField()
     from = ForeignKey(ModelFrom)
     to = ForeignKey(ModelTo)  

ModelFrom(models.Model):
    field_one = ManyToManyField(ModelTo, through=IntermediateField)
```

Then, we can just use an inline for IntermediateField in ModelFrom admin, easily checking the boxes etc